# Merge cells vertically if value is the same using a Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to merge vertically a column that has Employees sorted alphabetically. If it's the same value, I'd like to merge those cells.
Is this possible using a formula?

i.e

[image: i.e]

desired result:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Nre.png): [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in C2

```
=if(B2=B1,"",B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Use Data, Remove Duplicates to merge same value